# Inplace Jupyter

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

eu estou tentando modificar vários valores de uma coluna usando o **implace=True** no **jupyter**, contudo, eu não estou conseguindo. Alguém por favor consegue me ajudar com isso?

```
tabela['Cultura - Foco no Cliente'].replace('Acima da média',72, 'Na média', 71 ,'Muito acima da média',20,'Abaixo da média',15,inplace=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi a forma utilizada para passar parâmetros para o replace.

Repare que os valores a serem substituídos ficam em uma lista passada para `to_replace` e os valores que substituirão os primeiros em uma lista passada para `value`. Ambas as listas TÊM que ter o mesmo tamanho.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [5, 6, 7, 8]})

>>> df
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8

>>> df.replace(to_replace=[1,3], value=[100, 300])

     A  B
0  100  5
1    2  6
2  300  7
3    4  8

>>> df.replace(to_replace=[1,3], value=[100, 300], inplace=True)

>>> df
     A  B
0  100  5
1    2  6
2  300  7
3    4  8
```